# Code works for java but doesn't works for Android

Tags: android, sockets

Below code runs perfectly as java code in eclipse but it does not runs in Android Activity(MainActivity.java) results in application force closed

```
        try
    {
        Socket s=new Socket("192.168.0.6",9321);
        OutputStream d=s.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(d);
        dos.writeUTF("hii");
        s.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace at least

Comment: android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Use AsyncTask/Handler for network communication and add internet permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is you're trying to do network communication on the main thread.

You can't do that in Android.

Otherwise, the entire UI would completely freeze whenever you made a network request.

Try finding some examples of using the `AsyncTask` class to do network requests. That will handle the network request on another thread (so the UI doesn't freeze), and then deliver the response back.